Simple paths in a graph
Im confused, the question says how many simple paths are there from vertex a to vertex d, I only see 2 and that’s wrong. The correct answer is 5. And it’s not clear to me why. if someone could please explain.


I assume you counted a->b->d as one path, and then another from a->d.
However, the path from a->b->d is actually 4 distinct paths. You can take the inner route, the outer route, the first half inner and second half outer, or the first half outer and second half inner.
In other words, there are two routes between a->b, and two routes between b->c which can be chosen independently of one another.
This leads to 2 x 2 = 4 routes from a->b->c. Adding the route from a->d makes 5 routes total.
